# Python statannot module mixup error on boxplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to create a boxplot and compare data groups between one another.  The statistics work, but the plotting seems to be one data group (region) off.

I'm using the module `statannot` which is a life saver for data analysis.

Here is how I am calling the function:

```py
# Box plot with data
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.boxplot(x=AG, y=ss_mN, hue=R, hue_order=[Eq, Po], data=df)

# Statistical test for differences
# List of groups (AgeGroups)
hue_order = list(df[AG].unique())
# Create combinations to compare
box_pairs_1 = [((Age_Group_i, Eq), (Age_Group_i, Po)) 
               for Age_Group_i in hue_order]

# Add equator age groups
# Create combinations to compare
box_pairs_2 = [((LAG[0], Eq), (Age_Group_i, Eq)) 
               for Age_Group_i in hue_order]

box_pairs = box_pairs_1 + box_pairs_2
test_results = add_stat_annotation(ax, plot='boxplot', data=df, 
                                   x=AG, y=ss_mN, 
                                   hue=R, box_pairs=box_pairs,
                                   test='t-test_ind', text_format='star',
                                   loc='outside', verbose=2, 
                                   comparisons_correction=None, 
                                   line_offset=0.0, 
                                   line_offset_to_box=0.0, 
                                   line_height= 0.015, 
                                   fontsize='small') # 'bonferroni'

boxPlotBlackBorder() # Make borders black

# Add data points to the box plot
sns.stripplot(x=AG, y=ss_mN, hue=R, hue_order=[Eq, Po], data=df, color='.5', 
              size=5, linewidth=1, dodge=True)
# ax.legend(loc='best').set_title(R)

# gather plot attributes for legends
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

l = plt.legend(handles[0:2], labels[0:2], title=R)

ax.set_xlabel(A_G)
ax.set_ylabel(ss_mN)
ax = sns.despine() # takes the lines off on the right and top of the graph
f.savefig(os.path.join(HSF, 'SteadyState_Peel_force_ageGroup_BoxPlot_With' + 
                       'Data.pdf'), dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

When I define `box_pairs = box_pairs_1 + box_pairs_2` it merges the two lists together to compare each pair of data.

This is indeed the correct data to compare using student's t-test.

```py
[(('30-39', 'Equator'), ('30-39', 'Posterior')),
 (('60-69', 'Equator'), ('60-69', 'Posterior')),
 (('40-49', 'Equator'), ('40-49', 'Posterior')),
 (('50-59', 'Equator'), ('50-59', 'Posterior')),
 (('70-79', 'Equator'), ('70-79', 'Posterior')),
 (('30-39', 'Equator'), ('30-39', 'Equator')),
 (('30-39', 'Equator'), ('60-69', 'Equator')),
 (('30-39', 'Equator'), ('40-49', 'Equator')),
 (('30-39', 'Equator'), ('50-59', 'Equator')),
 (('30-39', 'Equator'), ('70-79', 'Equator'))]
```

Something happens when I add the second group `box_pairs_2`.  I should only compare each "Equator" data set but instead, it thinks they are "Posterior"...  I'm not sure how to reset this internally or figure out where the error is.

Here is what the plot looks like:
[image]
What should be happening is each "Equator" age group (light blue) should be compared between one another, not the dark blue.

I have modified the function to add a chi-square test between categorical data.

I am just not sure how even debug this issue to figure out why it is not updating the location of the boxplot I'm trying to reference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This was answered via GitHub, but what was missing was the `hue_order` which specifies, well, the order of groups being compared/plotted.